# Permission denied while running Lua file

Tags: lua, torch

I'm facing the following error message when running my code

> permission denied: ./batch-represent/main.lua

I already installed torch at home/anskush/torch.
and my main.lua

```
#!/home/ankush/torch th

require 'torch'
require 'optim'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Unix-like systems, you have to set a permission on a file to make it executable. Run the command `chmod 755 ./batch-represent/main.lua` and then run the script.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Programming languages that use an interpreter like LUA and PHP files only need to have read permission, unlike bash scripts which need executable permission because they are run directly.

Comment: @fred: That's only true if you invoke `lua` at the command line and pass it the program file. A Lua file must be executable if you want to invoke it as a stand-alone program that uses a shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

> ## !/home/ankush/torch th

I think you have space instead of slash, so the launcher attempts to execute a folder (`/home/ankush/torch`), which fails with "permission denied" message.

Try with `#!/home/ankush/torch/th` (assuming `th` executable/script is in that location and is executable).